# Why is implicit child to parent conversion in generic type parameters not possible?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I've been learning about covariance and contravariance in C#, but I can't understand something:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PersonCollection<Person> personCollection = new PersonCollection<Person>();
        IMyCollection<Teacher> myCollection = personCollection; // Here's the error:
        // Cannot implicitly convert type 'PersonCollection<Teacher>' to 'IMyCollection<Person>'
    }
}
class Person { }
class Teacher : Person { }
interface IMyCollection<T> { }
class PersonCollection<T> : IMyCollection<T> { }
```

as we all know, we can implicitly convert an instance of the derived class into the base class. So, in the code above, while the 'Teacher' class derives from the 'Person' class, an `IMyCollection<Teacher>` can't be converted to an `IMyCollection<Person>`, Why?!

Note: I want to know the reason, not the solution.

Comment: Keep reading on covariance and contravariance. This question is exactly that

Comment: That is what the Covariance and Contravariance in Generics means. If you declare your T in IMyColletion as Covariance, you can assign a class with a type param to a class with the declaration of an type argument of the base class

Comment: Please see the list in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance . Its very good defined.

Comment: @JPVenson I do know that. I just wanted to know the reason that why we can't do it normally

Comment: Because if you would get the first item in `myCollection`, you expect it to be a `Teacher`, but it may as well be a person.

Comment: You mention **three** different conversions in your question: You have one in the code, one in the error message, and one in your question text. You should really decide what you want to do…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Note: I want to know the reason, not the solution

While the reason for this is exactly why contra- and covariance exist, let me quickly show you an explanation with *your* example that highlights why this does not work:

So let’s assume the following setup code:

```
PersonCollection<Person> personCollection = new PersonCollection<Person>();

personCollection.Add(new Teacher("Teacher A"));
personCollection.Add(new Teacher("Teacher B"));
personCollection.Add(new Student("Student A"));
personCollection.Add(new Student("Student B"));
personCollection.Add(new Student("Student C"));
personCollection.Add(new Student("Student D"));
```

So now, I have a `PersonCollection<Person>` with two `Teacher` and four `Student` objects (here, `Student` also inherits from `Person`). This is completely valid since any `Teacher` and `Student` is also a `Person`. So I can add the elements to the collection.

Now, imagine the following was allowed:

```
IMyCollection<Teacher> myCollection = personCollection;
```

Now, I have a `myCollection` which apparently contains `Teacher` objects. But since this is just a reference assignment, `myCollection` is still the *exact same* collection as `personCollection`.

So `myCollection` will contain four `Student` objects although its contract defines that it only contains `Teacher` element. Doing the following should be totally allowed going by the contract of the interface:

```
Teacher teacher = personCollection[4];
```

But `personCollection[4]` is Student C, so obviously this would not work.

Since the compiler cannot make this verification during this item assignment, and since we want type safety instead of runtime validation, the only sane way the compiler can prevent this is by not allowing you to cast your collection to a `IMyCollection<Teacher>`.

You could make your `IMyCollection<T>` contravariant by declaring it as `IMyCollection<in T>` which would fix your situation and allow you to make that assignment but at the same time it would prevent you from retrieving a `Teacher` object out of it since it’s not covariant.

Generally, the only way to both set and retrieve generic values from a collection is to make it invariant (which is the default), which is also why all generic collections in the BCL are invariant and only some interfaces are contra- or covariant (e.g. `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant since it’s only about *retrieving* values).

---

Since you changed the error inside of your question to *“Cannot implicitly convert type 'PersonCollection' to 'IMyCollection'”*, let me also explain this case (turning this answer into a full contra- & covariance answer **sigh**…).

So the code would be the following for that:

```
PersonCollection<Teacher> personCollection = new PersonCollection<Teacher>();
IMyCollection<Person> myCollection = personCollection;
```

Again, let’s assume that this is valid and works. So now, we have a `IMyCollection<Person>` we can work with! So let’s add some persons here:

```
myCollection.Add(new Teacher("Teacher A"));
myCollection.Add(new Teacher("Teacher B"));
myCollection.Add(new Student("Student A"));
```

Whoops! The actual collection is still a `PersonCollection<Teacher>` which can only take `Teacher` objects. But the `IMyCollection<Person>` type allows us to add `Student` objects which are also persons! So this would fail at run-time, and again, since we want type safety at compile-time, the compiler has to disallow the assignment here.

This kind of assignment would only be valid for a covariant `IMyCollection<out T>` but that would also disallow us from adding elements of type `T` to it (for the same reasons as above).

Comment: I didn't understand, this example contains a collection mechanism, what if there is no 'Add(new Object())' method or something like that? or (as my example) what if I want to convert an 'IMyCollection<Teacher>' to an 'IMyCollection<Person>'?

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhmadi Excuse me that I just assumed collection semantics when your types is called `IMyCollection` and you didn’t give any more information. Any way, as I explained in my answer, you have to decide on whether you want your type contra-, co- or invariant. And depending on what you do, that has the mentioned implications on what operations you can include. Converting `IMyCollection<Teacher>` to `IMyCollection<Person>` is the same as converting from `PersonCollection<Teacher>`, so the same things apply there.

Answer (score 1):

Going by your source code as the source of truth, you actually misread the error.

> So, in the code above, while the class 'Teacher', is derived from
>   class 'Person', the `IMyCollection<Teacher>` can't be converted to
>   `IMyCollection<Person>` ,Why?

The actual error is

> Cannot implicitly convert type `PersonCollection<Person>` to
>   `IMyCollection<Teacher>`.

From an OO perspective at least, this is expected behavior.  It's important to understand that the default T is **invariant**.  That's why you ran into this problem to begin with.  Meaning if T is `Teacher` then T can only be `Teacher` and not `Person`.  Similarly, if T is `Person` then T can only be `Person` and not `Teacher`.

This is because Covariance and Contravariance are mutually exclusive.  There are ways to support both, but you have to split things up into interfaces that support Invariance, Covariance and Contravariance seperately. In your case, you would need to add support for Contravariance.  E.G.

`interface IMyCollection<in T> { }`

In other words, what comes into ( see `in` [generic modifier keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-generic-modifier)) the interface can be of type T.  Not what "goes out" (see `out` [generic modifier keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier)) or is returned from your interface (that would be Covariance).

Comment: Note that OP’s error message also does not match code, so there are actually three different example cases there.

Comment: Modified the question to point out what I took as the source of truth.